# Compare elements in two lists and make a new List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists and I want to make a new list by comparing the two lists and the new list should only contain those elements that contain in each of them.

```
List1=[[id: 1, label: 'cocoa'],[id: 2, label: 'apple'],[id: 3, label: 'cherry'],[id: 4, label: 'banana'],[id: 5, label: 'melon'],[id: 6, label: 'orange'],[id: 7, label: 'pineapple'],[id: 8], label: 'strawberry']
List2=[2,5,7,8]
expectedList = [[id: 2, label: 'apple'],[id: 5, label: 'melon'],[id: 7, label: 'pineapple'],[id: 8], label: 'strawberry']]
```

And the real code down below:

```
"options": [
                    {
                        "id": 58,
                        "label": "cocoa",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            118
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 59,
                        "label": "dark chocolate",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            120,
                            127
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 60,
                        "label": "apple",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            121,
                            128
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 61,
                        "label": "milk",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            122
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 62,
                        "label": "coconut",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            130
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 65,
                        "label": "cherry",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            126
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

So the first list would contain the json above, and the second list contains the numbers below that equals to some of the ID.

```
List<int> secondList = [58, 59, 60, 61];
```

Now when I want to generate a new list by comparing the secondList with the ID's of the first list, the third list is empty.

```
List thirdList = firstList.options.where((element) => secondList.contains(element.id)).toList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  var list2 = [2,5,7,8];
  var expectedList = list1.toSet().intersection(list2.toSet()).toList();

  print(expectedList.toString());
```

More information [here](https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-sets#:%7E:text=Dart%20Set%20Operations&text=intersection%20:-%20The%20intersection%20of,that%20belongs%20to%20set%20b.).

Respect to your info:

```
  var dataList = data['options'];
  var firstList = List<int>.generate(dataList.length, (i) => dataList[i]['id']);
  var secondList = [58, 59, 60, 61];
  var thirdList = firstList.toSet().intersection(secondList.toSet()).toList();
  var filtered = dataList.where((e) => thirdList.contains(e['id'])).toList();
  print(filtered.toString());
```

where:

```
const data = {
  "options": [
...
  ]
};
```

The result is:

```
[{id: 58, label: cocoa, swatch_value: null, products: [118]}, {id: 59, label: dark chocolate, swatch_value: null, products: [120, 127]}, {id: 60, label: apple, swatch_value: null, products: [121, 128]}, {id: 61, label: milk, swatch_value: null, products: [122]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, If you check my code I'm not comparing the two lists directly to each other, I'm comparing the second list against first list's ID's. so the code below based on your answer still is empty. thirdList = firstList.options
                                  .toSet()
                                  .intersection(secondList.toSet())
                                  .toList();

Comment: Thanks Gain, Now the list is returning only the id's but I want the list of the id's as in the json. So basically I want to filter the options list to contain only those lists that it's ID's are in the secondList. not just the ID's. Thanks again it was very helpfull but not what I want

Comment: Update my question

Comment: Thanks Bro, I know,  I have to study more. Thanks